# Is there any way to set up a trigger in ADF in such a way that if the file is updated or a new file is added it will run the pipeline

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

Let's say I have a file called test.csv in a container called TestFolder, I want to set the trigger in such a way that whenever there is a new file or if the current test.csv file is edited, the pipeline should be triggered for copying data to the sql table

Answer (score 0):

You can use Storage Event trigger
[image]

It would trigger an ADF pipeline whenever any one adds a new file or updates/edits an existing file

new edit:
[image]

Comment: thanks but when I edit something in the csv file it is adding to the existing table....like lets say there are 3 rows earlier, after editing something, it adds up and makes it 6 rows

Comment: ADF copy activity appends data when write behavior is Insert. You can leverage Upsert for update